# Using Fourier Series to high dimensional Image Sets

Tags: multivariable-calculus, fourier-series

A multivariate Fourier Series of $f(\mathbf{u})$ can be defined by:

$$f(\mathbf{u}) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}^{d}}^\infty C_n e^{2\pi i n \mathbf{u}}$$

where:

$$f: \mathbb{R}^{d} \to \mathbb{R}$$

My question is: how to use Fourier Series to approximate a function such as

$$f: \mathbb{R}^{d} \to \mathbb{R}^{q}$$

where $q > 1$?

For instance, is there a way to use Fourier Series to approximate a function like this:

$$f(x,y,z)=(x^3+zy^3, x^2z + y)$$

?

Is it safe solving it by doing:

$$f(x,y,z)=(g(x,y,z), h(x,y,z))$$

$$g(x,y,z) = \sum_{n,m,o}C_g^{mno} e^{2\pi i (mx+ny+oz) }$$

$$h(x,y,z) = \sum_{n,m,o}C_h^{mno} e^{2\pi i (mx+ny+oz) }$$

?

Comment: All you have to do is change your definition slightly and you are done. $$C_n \in \Bbb{C}^q$$ instead of $$C_n \in \Bbb{C}$$  See? Easy. But it is generally better form to use superscript $C^n$ for multiindices. This means your original Fourier series should have been written as $$\sum_{n\in\Bbb{Z}^d} C^n \exp\left(2\pi i n^Tu\right)$$

Comment: @NinadMunshi my question is not about multivariate Domains sets but about multivariate Image sets.

Comment: Do you see how the coefficient is the image?

Comment: @NinadMunshi, yeap, I gotta. Thank you!